# Pointcut is malformed: Class must not be null

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, aop, spring-aop

Out of a blue I'm getting "`Pointcut is malformed: Class must not be null`" error in Eclipse with a couple of Aspects classes. The code works fine but, without a change in those classes, Eclipse suddenly started reporting the error.
I'm trying to track down if the source of the problem is a eclipse platform/plugin update or a project's dependency update.

I'm using  Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.7.1.RELEASE Build Id: 201510041213  Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) and Spring IO Platform 2.0.0.

Does anyone have the same problem?

I'm posting one of the aspects code (although the problem probably is not here)

```
@Aspect
@Order(200)
@Component
public class FooAspect {

    @Around("execution(public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.acme.endpoints.controller..*.*(..)) && " +
            "@target(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController) && " + 
            "@annotation(com.acme.endpoints.annotations.FooAnnotation)")
    public Object doCurrencyConversion(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        String bar = extractBar(pjp);
        ResponseEntity<?> retVal;
        retVal = (ResponseEntity<?>) pjp.proceed();
        processFooBar(retVal, bar);
        return retVal;
    }

    private String extractBar(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        return "...";
    }

    private void processFooBar(ResponseEntity<?> retVal, String targetBar) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the errors have gone away. What I have done is change the way I managed the Spring dependencies.

Before I imported the platform BOM in my parent POM so that all my modules inherit it as described in the Spring website with:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement><repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

With this configuration, some version overrides where not working and since the BOM version I'm using is a SNAPSHOT, the actual versions of the dependencies where changing everyday.

What I did was to set the BOM as my parent's parent, this way the version overrides worked as expected an everything compiled without a hint:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```