# Spring Data JPA Pointcut is malformed: Class must not be null warning in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am using SPring Data JPA. I had created a AOP Aspect to switch between databases like when read connection is required swap to replica, when write connection is required swap to Master. But Eclipse shows the warning **Pointcut is malformed: Class must not be null.**

```
package com.casa.core.sqljpa.annotation;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.casa.core.sqljpa.DbContextHolder;
import com.casa.core.sqljpa.enums.DbType;

@Aspect
@Component
public class WriteConnectionInterceptor implements Ordered {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WriteConnectionInterceptor.class);

    private int order;

    @Value("20")
    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("@annotation(writeConnection)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, WriteConnection writeConnection) throws Throwable {
        try {
            logger.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": In Write Only Connection");
            DbContextHolder.setDbType(DbType.MASTER);
            Object result = pjp.proceed();
            DbContextHolder.clearDbType();

            return result;
        } finally {
            // restore state
            DbContextHolder.clearDbType();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help to fix issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254795/pointcut-is-malformed-class-must-not-be-null

Comment: No, I had checked the solution, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: The aspect syntax as such is correct. So you your problem cause is somewhere else. Please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (code, configuration, build files for Maven or Gradle) in order for us to reproduce the problem and also edit your question, mentioning versions of IDE and aspect-related plugins used just in case others cannot reproduce the problem in their IDEs.